# what is the locus of equation $\sin(x) =1/2$

Tags: locus

I want to ask that, different  values of the argument  will satisfy  the  equation  like pi/2,2*pi/3,etc. (sorry I don't  have pi (22/7) symbol  in my keyboard)
In this situation  how will draw the locus because there are infinite points on the number line satisfying  the condition . 
please  help

Comment: A little remark $22/7=3.142857...$ is only  an approximation of $\pi=3.141592...$.

Comment: It's quite common to not have a $\pi$ button on your keyboard (I think Mac users can get to it with some fancy combination like cmd-alt-p, or something). That is why we use MathJax [(see this link)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so we just have to write `$\pi$` to get it to appear. One can, of course, do more complicated stuff as well: `$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}$` gives $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: isn't that cos(x)=1/2 ?? @JeanMarie

Comment: You are right. I am going to change my remark.

Comment: (revised remark/answer) : There are an infinity of roots, of two kinds : $x=\pi/6+k 2 \pi$ and $x=5\pi/6+k 2 \pi$ for any positive or negative integer $k$.